# Customer account dashboard tracking URL

Tags: orders, customer-account, dashboard, shipment-tracking

In the account dashboard inside the placed orders (http://www.domain.com/sales/order/view/order_id/), we want to echo the tracking URL from the transactional order email.

The default tracking popup contains the wrong tracking URL and we do not want to use the popup.

We just want to echo the correct tracking URL.
Off course only when the order is shipped and really got a tracking URL.

How can we achieve that?

Answer (score 2):

Edit `sales/view.phtml` and put it somewhere. (Maybe add a extra block.phtml)

`Mage_Sales_Model_Order` has a method `getTracksCollection()` which should contain tracking numbers for a order.

Just walk and display them according.